# Voto de cierre por duplicada que no he hecho

Tags: soporte, cierre-de-preguntas, motivos-de-cierre

En la pregunta [sobre redes Neuronales](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/40700/que-lenguaje-de-programacion-me-recomiendan-para-desarrollo-de-una-rn-red-neuron) aparece que he votado para cerrarla como duplicada.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y yo no recuerdo haber hecho mas que un downvote. EDIT: y un voto de cierre por opinión personal

Miré en el historial y la ultima que sale que voté para cerrar fue:

>
`lois6b ¿Cómo traducir un código de HTML/jQuery a React? [cerrada]  Cerrar  el 12 dic. a las 13:12`

Y en estadisticas me sale que hoy no casteé votos de cierre por duplicado.

**¿Por qué sale mi nombre entre los que votaron para cerrar esa pregunta?**

Comment: Cuando se vota para cerrar una pregunta de requieren 5 votos sin importar el motivo. Cuando hay 5 votos se muestra el mayoritario. En este caso hay 3 de duplicado y 2 de opiniones.

Comment: Aaah, @MiquelColl pensaba que eran 5 del mismo tipo. Que cosas. en este caso es obvio que es duplicada pero si no estuviera de acuerdo y ver ahi mi nombre...  XD

Comment: Estaba convencido de que ya había una respuesta en meta explicándolo, pero no puedo encontrarla

Comment: @MiquelColl Esa deberia ser la respuesta a la pregunta

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Cuando se vota para cerrar se requieren 5 votos sin importar el motivo.

Cuando hay 5 votos se muestra el mayoritario.

En este caso concreto hay 3 de duplicado y 2 de opiniones por lo que se ha marcado como duplicado como si todos los usuarios lo hubieran votado como tal.

Comment: de hecho has conseguido escribir sin palabras que lleven tilde xD

Comment: huh. Curioso haha! Gracias por la edicion. Ahora si que no hay acentos en la respuesta =P. (aunque este comentario le falta a edicion y a si.... :( )

Comment: ahahah gracias por la respuesta oficial.